# Facebook FB Comments box post to wall?

Tags: facebook

Alrighty!

So I have a blog that I have a FB comments box on. When I post the blog I also post a blurb about the blog to the fan page and then database the post id with the post.

The comment box works good. But is it possible that when a user posts a comment in the FB comment box I can also have that post as a comment to the actual post on the fan page?

Seeing as I have the id of the post I would think I could send the comment in the FB box as a comment of the post on the fan page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the comment box in that manner but you could get the post message from string and repost with graph api to your wall.

refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#publishing